# Visual Studio 2008 - StarTeam integration

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, starteam

I wonder if there are any plugin for StarTeam Integration in VS 2008? I installed StarTeam Client 2009 but had a horrible accuracy for the project files. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StarTeam has a full suite of integration tools for VS 2008, 2010 and 2012 and these can be found and downloaded from the following location,

http://supportline.microfocus.com/websync/StarTeam2009EA.aspx

and browse to the Visual Studio integration section.

Thanks.